# What is the brand and model of this button camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, video, generic-brand

Does anyone know the brand and model of this button camera?[image: image of camera in question]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When asking questions like this it helps all concerned to provide as much information as you have available. Had you done so one possible answer would have been immediately obvious. ie

If you ask the owner he may well tell you

Here is his Facebook page  - [**Jonathan Novick**](https://www.facebook.com/Jonathan-Novick-536601063134287/)

Here are [5 of his you tube videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNZbUpC0DXbDNMbmEqPAiAw)

And [**a related article on using that camera **](http://www.hypeness.com.br/2014/08/anao-grava-documentario-com-camera-escondida-para-mostrar-o-preconceito-que-sofre-diariamente/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've just sent him a message in facebook. Though I noticed that his last posts were from two years ago, when his vids were filmed.

Comment: @user125797  Doesn't look too hopeful. :-(. Nothing past late 2014. 
Here is his linked in page as 
IT Coordinator at the NYC Mayor's Office for People with Disabilities 
- https://www.linkedin.com/in/jonathan-novick-10901339 || Google+ https://plus.google.com/102857825259570098425